# Find deleted username from SID in Windows Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, sid

I have a need to find a username that was deleted from the AD using only the SID.  I understand that Windows AD leaves being a Tombstone file that might contain this information.  Can someone give me the syntax of a command or post a document that might point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Viewing deleted objects in Active Directory - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/258310

Unless the user has been deleted for longer than the tombstone lifetime of your AD, it will be in there.

Edit: And here's a better article, with pictures! - http://www.petri.co.il/deleted-objects-in-active-directory.htm

Answer (score 1):

I also googled around and indeed, do as mentioned on the site http://www.petri.co.il/deleted-objects-in-active-directory.htm.

Only, in the search box you choose as filter `(&(isDeleted=*)(objectSid=yourobjectSID))`

Example:
Filter: `(&(isDeleted=*)(objectSid=S-1-5-21-1601936709-1892662786-3840804712-315762))`

Answer (score 1):

I found [this post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/9e37449c-a5b3-49b0-8ecc-6f579946d419/how-to-search-deleted-objects-by-sid?forum=winserverDS) helped easily find the deleted user (in my case group) name from a SID.  It seemed much easier than the previous solutions posted.

Import-Module ActiveDirectory

```
get-adobject -Filter 'isdeleted -eq $true -and name -ne "Deleted Objects" -and objectSID -like "Enter SID here"' -IncludeDeletedObjects -Properties samaccountname,displayname,objectsid
```

Notes:

- Run in the domain where the deleted account resides
- Works on Windows 2008 R2 and above, I didn't try lower versions
- If you run 'Active Directory Module for Windows Powershell', you won't have to import any module